Как сделать Unity event (On death)
Есть Игрок. У него есть On death event. Нужно создать скрипт, привязать его к обьекту в сцене и в скрипте написать действие? Нужно Loadscene if игрок умер (разные способы). Как это все сделать?
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class EndGame12PlayerDeath : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var boxes = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Player");
        if (boxes.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Player is dead");
            SceneManager.LoadScene("Main Menu", LoadSceneMode.Additive);
        }
    }
}



И что, этот код не работает?
